# Can't add DifferentialEquation.jl to Julia 1.7.0

Tags: package, julia

I recently went from Julia 1.6.3 to 1.7.0. I copied the *Manifest* and the *Project.toml* files to the new *environments* folder and updated the Manifest file to the newer version according to instructions. Everything worked fine. However, when I later tried to add DifferentialEquations.jl I got this error:

```
(@v1.7) pkg> precompile
Precompiling project...
✗ DiffEqNoiseProcess
✗ DiffEqFinancial
✗ StochasticDiffEq
✗ MultiScaleArrays
✗ DifferentialEquations
        
0 dependencies successfully precompiled in 30 seconds (252 already precompiled)
ERROR: The following 2 direct dependencies failed to precompile:
DiffEqNoiseProcess [77a26b50-5914-5dd7-bc55-306e6241c503] 
Failed to precompile DiffEqNoiseProcess [77a26b50-5914-5dd7-bc55-306e6241c503] to C:\Users\*user*\.julia\compiled\v1.7\DiffEqNoiseProcess\jl_F949.tmp.

WARNING: Method definition Type##kw(Any, Type{Base.MPFR.BigFloat}, Base.Irrational{:fourinvπ}) in module StatsFuns at irrationals.jl:182 overwritten in module IrrationalConstants on the same line (check for duplicate calls to `include`).
** incremental compilation may be fatally broken for this module **

WARNING: Method definition Type##kw(Any, Type{Base.MPFR.BigFloat}, Base.Irrational{:twoinvπ}) in module StatsFuns at irrationals.jl:182 overwritten in module IrrationalConstants on the same line (check for duplicate calls to `include`).
** incremental compilation may be fatally broken for this module **

...
```

It continues with similar warnings for a while and finally I get this:

```
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: SciMLBase not defined
Stacktrace:
[1] top-level scope
@ C:\Users\manfr\.julia\packages\DiffEqNoiseProcess\9NzQP\src\solve.jl:1
[2] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
@ Base .\Base.jl:418
[3] include(x::String)
@ DiffEqNoiseProcess C:\Users\manfr\.julia\packages\DiffEqNoiseProcess\9NzQP\src\DiffEqNoiseProcess.jl:1
[4] top-level scope
@ C:\Users\manfr\.julia\packages\DiffEqNoiseProcess\9NzQP\src\DiffEqNoiseProcess.jl:23
[5] include
@ .\Base.jl:418 [inlined]
[6] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String},
dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String},
concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::String)
@ Base .\loading.jl:1318
[7] top-level scope
@ none:1
[8] eval
@ .\boot.jl:373 [inlined]
[9] eval(x::Expr)
@ Base.MainInclude .\client.jl:453
[10] top-level scope
@ none:1
in expression starting at
C:\Users\manfr\.julia\packages\DiffEqNoiseProcess\9NzQP\src\solve.jl:1
in expression starting at C:\Users\manfr\.julia\packages\DiffEqNoiseProcess\9NzQP\src\DiffEqNoiseProcess.jl:1
ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile DiffEqNoiseProcess [77a26b50-5914-5dd7-bc55-
306e6241c503] to C:\Users\manfr\.julia\compiled\v1.7\DiffEqNoiseProcess\jl_5956.tmp.
Stacktrace:
[1] error(s::String)
@ Base .\error.jl:33
[2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IO, internal_stdout::IO,
ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
@ Base .\loading.jl:1466
[3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
@ Base .\loading.jl:1410
[4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
@ Base .\loading.jl:1120
[5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
@ Base .\loading.jl:1013
[6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
@ Base .\loading.jl:997
[7] include 
@ .\Base.jl:418 [inlined]
[8] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String},
dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String},
concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::Nothing)
@ Base .\loading.jl:1318
[9] top-level scope
@ none:1
[10] eval
@ .\boot.jl:373 [inlined]
[11] eval(x::Expr)
@ Base.MainInclude .\client.jl:453
[12] top-level scope
@ none:1
in expression starting at
C:\Users\manfr\.julia\packages\DifferentialEquations\el96s\src\DifferentialEquations.jl:1
```

I've tried to build, precompile, delete the package folder and add it again, but nothing seems to work. I also tried to add the package to my Julia 1.6.3 installation, and that works fine. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manifests are version specific (since package versions can be Julia version specific). Re-resolve your packages without the manifest.

Comment: a lot of the problem is that Julia 1.7 introduced a new manifest format that is better, but incompatible with the old one.

Comment: Thank you, I replaced it with the original which worked.

Comment: *Re-resolve your packages without the manifest* --  Sorry, could you explain how to do it, please?

Comment: Just use `]resolve`